# horizontal scroll bar appears too early

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem with a horizontal scroll bar, it appears much earlier then it should be. At the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4JmjJ/3/) you can see a lot of unused space to the right of the form that causing the problem, but i cant figure out why is that space there. (marked as red square on the screenshot). You can find all CSS that im using in jsfiddle.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<section class="content">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span10 article">
            <div class="block">
                <div class="section">
                    <h4>Online Application</h4>
                    <div class="row-fluid form-horizontal">
                        <div class="span6">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="contact_name_1">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="contact_name_2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="contact_email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Home Phone</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="contact_phone_home">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Cell Phone</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="contact_phone_cell">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="button" value="Start Application" onClick="obertka25()">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section></div>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLZCi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a section that starts with

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
```

and that's where the problem starts.  For some reason it kicks the .article div into some type of fixed width.  It has something to do with the line

```
.row-fluid .span10 {
    width: 82.90598290598291%;
    *width: 82.8527914166212%;
}
```

Disabling that allowed it to go full-width again.  I couldn't figure out why, when given a % width, it went to fixed-width.

**EDIT**:  There is a `min-width` style on the body tag, and when I disable that I see normal width behavior from the `.row-fluid .span10` element.  I suspect that the horizontal scrollbars are due to that